# How to use ts_headline with multiple languages

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I am using full-text search against a single table column. The data in the column could be of any language with no way to determine the language ahead of time. Assuming I only care about some subset of possible languages (for example English and Spanish), I can easily generate a list of lexemes for the vector:

```
to_tsvector('english', my_column) || to_tsvector('spanish', my_column)
```

and for the query:

```
to_tsquery('english', 'something') || to_tsquery('spanish', 'something')
```

This works as expected.

However, I would also like to return the column value with the matches highlighted, but `ts_headline` accepts a single configuration, the document and the query as parameters. I can write something like:

```
ts_headline(
  'english',
  my_column,
  to_tsquery('english', 'amor') || to_tsquery('spanish', 'amor')
)
```

but this will only apply the highlighting based on the configuration passed to `ts_headline` -- so in the example above, the word "amoroso" will be included in the result, but will *only* be highlighted if I set the configuration to "spanish".

I could run `ts_headline` for each configuration and return the results as an array, but then I would still have to combine them after running the query, which is less than ideal.

Is there a way to apply the highlighting based on multiple languages?

EDIT: Alternatively, given a document, its lexemes and the query lexemes, is there a way to return the list of matched words in the document along with their locations in the document?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
case ts_rank(t."document_en", to_tsquery('english', p_query_or)) > ts_rank(t."document_fr", to_tsquery('french', p_query_or))
           when true then ts_headline('english', t."title", to_tsquery('english', p_query_or))
           else ts_headline('french', t."title", to_tsquery('french', p_query_or))
        end as title
```

Comment: Curious pattern: `CASE <condition> WHEN true THEN ... ELSE ... END`. Why not just `CASE WHEN <condition> THEN ... ELSE ... END`?